# getting 'only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars' error

Tags: python

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from math import sin, pi

y = pi
x = np.linspace(0, 3*y, 500)
plt.plot(x, sin(x**2))
title("A simple Graph")
plt.show()
```

getting

> 'only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars'

error while running this code

Comment: Quick questions: why use math at all? Numpy contains both the sin and pi that you are importing from math. Since you are already using `np.linespace`, why not use `np.pi` and `np.sin`. To keep you code the same, just add `np.` in front of sin and it should fix the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change
    `plt.plot(x,sin(x**2))`
to
    `plt.plot(x,np.sin(x**2))`

Answer (score 1):

You may use this code instead:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from math import sin,pi 
y=pi
x = np.linspace(0, 3*y, 500)
plt.plot(x,[sin(_**2) for _ in x])
title("A simple Graph")
plt.show()
```

The second argument of the plot function was not correct.

Comment: But why was the second argument incorrect? What was the problem with it?